# Attaching a file to a comment with Basecamp API

Tags: api, curl, basecamp

I'm attempting to attach a file to a comment in a message with the Basecamp API.  According to the documentation, I first upload the file as so:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/xml' -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' -u 123456789:X -X POST -d @/my/path/test.txt https://myurl.com/upload
```

This returns an id, so I know the file was uploaded.  I then try to attach this file to a comment in a message:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/xml' -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -u 123456789:X -X POST -d '<comment><body>This is a test</body><attachments><name>blah</name><file><file>$id</file><content-type>application/text</content-type><original-filename>test.txt</original-filename></file></attachments></comment>' https://myurl/posts/987654321/comments.xml
```

The comment is uploaded however the attachment is not.  Does anyone know why the attachment would not be uploaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's your only problem, but the value of `$id` isn't interpolated when you use single quotes, and so you're passing the string `'$id'` instead of the value of `$id`.

Either use `'...<file>'$id'</file>...'` or `"...<file>$id</file>..."`